# MYSQL - NOT vs var=false

Tags: mysql, sql

In the last past days I noticed something weird optimizing my query.
I have a simple query which does something like:

```
   SELECT id,name,amount FROM reservations WHERE NOT canceled ORDER BY name ASC
```

I noticed mysql wasn't using any index, so I started doing some experiments.
Accidentally I replaced the "NOT canceled" with "canceled=false", and then, Mysql started using "canceled" as index.
After that I tried using the opposite:

```
   SELECT ... FROM reservations WHERE canceled ORDER BY ...
```

Same result! When I change that to "canceled=true" the index works again.

My question is: HOW COME?! Isn't using "NOT" the "elegant" way? Anyhow I didn't expect for it to make any difference.

I'm using **InnoDB** as the engine, but i get same result using MyISAM.
Can someone clarify things up?
Thanks.

**Edit: Table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE `reservations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `trip_code` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `departure_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `canceled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_date` date NOT NULL,
  `creator_user` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `last_update_user` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `trip_code` (`trip_code`),
  KEY `departure_date` (`departure_date`),
  KEY `created_date` (`created_date`),
  KEY `canceled` (`canceled`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=123181 ;
```

Comment: Server version: 5.1.43-community

Comment: Can you post up the table's DDL.

Comment: A column with only 2 values might not be selective enough to benefit from using an index anyway. Which query runs faster?

Comment: Could you try to change the `canceled` column's type to `bool`, And tell me if it changes something?

Comment: How many rows have value `0` and how many value `1`?

Comment: MySQL changes the column automatically to tinyint. The issue here is not why the index is used or not, but why "NOT var1" is different from "var1=false".

Comment: You still haven't answered my question about how many have `0`  and how many `1`? Would help to have an idea about size of table and also useful for anyone wanting to reproduce the issue.

Comment: `7598` have `0` and `508` have `1`. @MartinSmith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with MYSQL, but thinking logically, I understand it like this:
Index is like a phone book, when you are searching for "Cohen", you can get it right away.
But if you are looking for **NOT** "Cohen", you will have to run over every entry, and check if it's different from "Cohen".
So when you are looking for **specific value**, it looks just for it. And when you are using **NOT**, it looks for any other value that can fit inside `tinyint(1)` (as I understand it's not only `1` or `0`, is it?).

Comment: I think they indicate in the question that `WHERE canceled` does not use an index too. Although not that clear what "Same result" refers to.

Comment: Well I think, `WHERE canceled` is true when the `canceled`'s value is 1, 2 or 3... So it's still not a **specific value** predicate

Comment: Ignoring the fact that the column is declared as `tinyint(1)` the same non specificity would be the case for `WHERE canceled = true`.

Comment: +1 Actually I was wrong about that. `WHERE X` will return a row with an X value of `2`. `WHERE X=true` doesn't. I guess the `true` gets cast to `int` first then compared against the value so this is a sargable predicate.

Comment: This is the closest answer I got from the post. I wasn't looking for the best way to implement my query, in fact I was only interested in knowing why is there a difference between `var=false` and `NOT var`

Answer (score 3):

Even though it's using an index, the index (believe it or not) may make your query slower. It's a little weird, but it's related to index selectivity. It's generally presented in columns of type boolean.

**It's descrbed like:**

> "How different values of a field are. It is a number from 0-1,
>   although you can also think of it as a percentage. A value of 1, or
>   100%, means that each value in the field is unique"

**It's important to consider becouse:**

> "MySQL has a cost-based optimizer. This means that MySQL calculates
>   the costs of different ways of performing a query and then chooses the
>   cheapest one. Well, calculating the costs is an inexact science. So an
>   estimate is taken, and the estimate is wrong sometimes."

**Plain simple:**

If the data you're looking has more or less 20% of the same value (for example, cancelled has 40% of your table) then, it's simple to just do a table scan.

**EDIT:**

Regarding your question, EXPLAIN tells you that MySQL is using an index. But, it might not be good, the only way to note whether your optimization is better is to test performance. Also, consider the costo of INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE operations to keep that index. Do some profiling with and without the index.

Take a look at this:

- http://sheeri.com/archives/77
- http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/06/02/indexes-in-mysql/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that now. Regardless, the question still remains. how come "NOT var1" differs from "var1=false"?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS C, 0 AS X UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS C, 1 AS X UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS C, 2 AS X ) T
WHERE X=true
```

Returns

```
'2', '1'
```

And

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS C, 0 AS X UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS C, 1 AS X UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS C, 2 AS X ) T
WHERE X
```

Returns

```
'2', '1'
'3', '2'
```

So it seems that in the first case the `true` gets cast to `int` and then used in a seekable predicate whereas in the second case the column value is implicitly cast. Implicit casts generally make a condition unsargable.

Looking at the explain plan for your query with `WHERE canceled = true` gives

```
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type |    table     | type | possible_keys |   key    | key_len |  ref  | rows |            Extra            |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | reservations | ref  | canceled      | canceled |       1 | const |    1 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------------+
```

Whereas for  `WHERE canceled` you get

```
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+-----+---------+-----+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type |    table     | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows |            Extra            |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+-----+---------+-----+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | reservations | ALL  |               |     |         |     |    2 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+-----+---------+-----+------+-----------------------------+
```

So it appears that it can't even consider the index on `canceled` as a possible option in this case.